# Keeping Bookmarks During Windows10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

Will converting to Windows 10 erase Bookmarks? My friend upgraded to Windows 10 and her Bookmarks appear gone.

Comment: See here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1075071

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the browser but chances are they're there but you're running the 'wrong' browser.
IE10 has a new browser called edge, and its set as default.It does not seem to pick up IE bookmarks. You might need to export and import bookmarks then (but I'm not sure about the process for that) or better yet, set your preferred browser as the default through the default program app

If you're in doubt, most browsers would let you back up, and a full system backup is a great idea before a major update like this.

I've not seen any bookmark loss in either chrome, IE  or firefox.